# Как настроить работу с цветами в sass?

Tags: css, sass, scss

В данном примере кода `&:hover` использует функцию `darken` для затемнения цвета, 
но я собираюсь задавать **`а`** цвет за счет специального класса в **HTML** и эти классы могут меняться, `&:hover` не будет ни чего знать о переменной **`$color-link`** , как сделать что бы на `&:hover` он автоматически определял цвет ссылки и применял к нему функцию **`darken`** ?

```
a
    text-decoration: none
    color: $color-link
    &:hover
        text-decoration: none
        color: darken( $color-link, 10% )
```

Comment: Скорее всего никак таким способом.

Comment: видимо только js )

Comment: А что именно мешает прописать параллельно условия для `a` с неким классом?